# WSO2 DAS Realtime Monitoring

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

Could anyone please tell me where are tutorials or examples for WSO2 DAS 3.5.0 real time monitoring?

The scenario: there are WSO2 AM, WSO2 ESB and WSO2 DAS installed in different machines. Managers want DAs to collect real time data from both AM and ESB servers and monitor some information, like APIs traffic, which Apps invokes API and so on.

Thanks,
Sean

Answer (score 0):

You can enable stats in both products and publish stats to DAS instance using thrift. Please refer [Publishing API Statistics APIM document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Publishing%20API%20Runtime%20Statistics%20Using%20REST%20Client).
Once you follow these steps it will deploy a Capp in the DAS which will consist required streams and other artefacts.

Similarly you can configure ESB statistics and collect all the statistics. Please refer the documentations on [Mediation statistics](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Mediation%20Statistics) and [transport statistics](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Transport%20Statistics).

Now you can use these event streams and add UI publishers and publish real time events to analytic dashboard portal of the DAS. You can use wizard to create gadgets and dashboards in the portal. Please refer the document on [Visualizing Results in the analytics Dashboard](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Visualizing%20Results%20in%20the%20Analytics%20Dashboard).
Even you can write your own real time custom gadgets as well, please refer this [blog post](http://blog.tharik.org/2015/09/create-your-own-custom-real-time-gadget.html) for more details.

Once ESB 5.0.0 and APIM 2.0.0 are being released, there will be analytics distribution (DAS pack with pre configured gadgets, dashboards and other artefacts). You can refer articles on [Analyzing ESB with the Analytics Dashboard](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Analyzing+ESB+with+the+Analytics+Dashboard).